# How to draw commutative diagrams?

Tags: macros, diagrams, xy-pic, tikz-cd

Can anyone help me in giving commands for commutative diagrams in LaTeX ? It doesn't seem to appear properly in the LaTeX guides that I have. A command for a simple triangular diagram with arrows associated to maps would be good enough, or maybe some appropriate reference.

Comment: sure, how about [a quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=commutative+diagram+tikz&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=osY&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=commutative+diagram+tikz+site:+tex.stackexchange.com&oq=commutative+diagram+tikz+site:+tex.stackexchange.com&gs_l=serp.3...1925.8811.0.8945.37.32.3.0.0.0.246.3199.21j9j2.32.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.A8I6R-qhCsg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46865395,d.cGE&fp=dcda5743378e995b&biw=1280&bih=878)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html

Comment: One single authentic source on `xy-pic` is at [TUG](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) and its [userguide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf) and [crisp Introduction ppt](http://math.arizona.edu/~swig/documentation/xypic/Xypic.pdf). More [in depth reference guide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyrefer.pdf)

Comment: The most modern package is [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). The documentation includes numerous examples.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For simple and complex diagrams, I'd recommend `tikz-cd`. If you are not comfortable with using the macros, there is also a web-based GUI editor at https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/.  The following example can be viewed in the editor under [this link (click)](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#eyJub2RlcyI6W3sicG9zaXRpb24iOlswLDBdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkEifSx7InBvc2l0aW9uIjpbMSwwXSwidmFsdWUiOiJCIn0seyJwb3NpdGlvbiI6WzEsMV0sInZhbHVlIjoiQyJ9XSwiZWRnZXMiOlt7ImZyb20iOjAsInRvIjoxLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImYifSx7ImZyb20iOjEsInRvIjoyLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImcifSx7ImZyb20iOjAsInRvIjoyLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImcgXFxjaXJjIGYiLCJsYWJlbFBvc2l0aW9uIjoicmlnaHQifV19).

Let's see an easy triangular diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} & B \arrow{d}{g} \\
     & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arrow takes as argument the "steps" where it has to go: `r` stands for "right", `d` stands for "down"; also `u` stands for "up" and `l` for "left".

A similar syntax is available with Xy-pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]^{f} \ar[dr]_{g\circ f} & B \ar[d]^{g} \\
 & C
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note how the labels are positioned: `^` means above the arrow, `_` means below; above and below are with respect to the direction of the arrow: rotate it counterclockwise until it points from left to right.

[image]

As you see, the results are pretty much alike. While I used to use Xy-pic, I'm now more convinced that `tikz-cd` can be better, as it relies on the powerful TikZ/PGF library.

Comment: `tikz-cd` is significantly better. It is more flexible and powerful, and just compare the hooked arrows with those of `xy-pic`.

Comment: @Gaussler I fully agree! I have used Xy-pic quite extensively, with good results, but `tikz-cd` is much more powerful and intuitive. You won't find a single hook arrow in my older diagrams. `;-)`

Comment: How can I arrange for the triangle to be equilateral? In other words, how do I centralize $C$ above?

Comment: `A \arrow{rr}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} && B \arrow{dl}{g} \\ & C` (you may have to adjust the `column sep`)

Comment: can I put the diagram inside a colorbox?

Comment: @DavidWarrenKatz Of course you can: `\colorbox{red}{\xymatrix{...}}`

Comment: The tikzcd GUI editor is fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! This website is indeed amazing. If someone is looking for a website to draw commutative diagrams online, this will be what they are exactly looking for. I even suggest that you should post a question "Which website allows drawing commutative diagrams online " and answer it yourself, so that others can more easily search it!

Comment: Do you mind also adding https://q.uiver.app/ to the post? It’s similar but seems more powerful

Comment: @GarethMa Sorry, but I can't understand how it works.

Comment: @egreg Umm you double click on a square to add a vertex. Then type some latex say `$\mathbb{Z}$` to render it on that square. Then **drag** an arrow from one square to another (using mouse / touch screen both work)

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use the `psmatrix` environment, from `pst-node`. The objects are first described as nodes in a matrix, then the arrows are described. In this description, nodes can be given a name, or are described by their pair of indices `i, j` in the matrix. See documentation of pst-node for details on how to connect nodes or more generally how to fine-tune the look of a diagram.

You can compile with `pdflatex` if you use the `--shell-escape` switch (TeX Live, MacTeX) or  `--enable-write18`  (MiKTeX), and use the `pdf` option for the document class: this loads the `auto-pst-pdf` package. Alternatively, you can  load  the latter package, `after` pstricks and its family.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=1.2cm}
\begin{psmatrix}
  (X, d) & (X_1 ,d_1 )\\%
   & (X_2 ,d_2)
%%%
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{T_1} \ncline{1,1}{2,2}\nbput{T_2 }
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2}\naput[npos=0.45]{T}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]