# How to define mathematical functions by the action on an element?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I would like to define a mathematical function by its action. Something like

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \begin{document}
     \[
        \begin{array}{cccc}
         f\colon & R\times R & \rightarrow & R\times R\\
                 & v & \mapsto & f(v)
        \end{array}
      \]
      \end{document}
```

In this way, spacing is horrible. What is the best way to produce it?

I want the elements in the second line centered with respect to the element of the first line.

Comment: This looks a little bit like a commutative diagram? There are many related question like [Commutative Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783/16595); see also [tag:tikz-cd] and [tag:xy-pic].

Answer (score 9):

I would go with something simple and, at least for me, quite classical:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  f\colon R\times R \to R\times R,\quad v \mapsto f(v)
\]
or
\[
  f\colon \biggl\{\begin{array}{@{}r@{\;}l@{}}
    R\times R &\to R\times R
  ,\\
    v &\mapsto f(v)
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be ``\;`` rather than ``\,``. And the AMS prefers `\colon` to the simple `:`

Comment: @egreg Or maybe `{@{} r @{} >{{}} l @{}}` to mimic `amsmath`'s alignment process?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In this case it's exactly the same.

Comment: @egreg I'd had `\;` in one version, I dunno what I've done to it. And thx for the colon tip, I've never actually heard of it.

Answer (score 5):

One might do with `array`, by removing the intercolumn spaces. But the result won't be good anyway.

Here are three other ways, in increasing order of preference, to accomplish your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec} % just to get small section titles
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\section{First way}
With only \texttt{amsmath}
\begin{align*}
f\colon R\times R &\to R\times R\\
v & \mapsto f(v)
\end{align*}

\section{Second way}
With \texttt{amsmath} and \texttt{xy}
\[
\xymatrix@R=0pt@C=1pc{
 f\colon R\times R \ar[r] & R\times R \\
 {\hphantom{f\colon{}}} v \ar@{|->}[r] & f(v)
}
\]

\section{Third way}
With \texttt{amsmath} and \texttt{tikz-cd}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0pt,column sep=1pc]
 f\colon R\times R \arrow{r} & R\times R \\
  {\hphantom{f\colon{}}} v \arrow[mapsto]{r} & f(v)
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I personally prefer the *First way*:  I find it easier to parse than the other two approaches, because it produces `\to` and `\mapsto` that are horizontally aligned.

Comment: NICE! Quick question: suppose we need to write the set "Domain of the function `f`". I assume that you are with me that the name of this set is `dom(f)`. So, how would you write `dom`: `\mathrm{dom}`, `\operatorname{dom}`, ...?

Comment: @manooooh It’s obviously an operator

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an `array` in the first place. Assuming you mare using the `amsmath` package (recommendable), I'd simply write

```
\begin{gather*}
   f\colon R\times R \to R\times R
   \\
   v \mapsto f(v)
\end{gather}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have found is

```
\begin{align*}
  f\colon R\times R &\to R\times R\\
  \setbox0\hbox{$R\times R$}%
  \makebox[\wd0][c]{$v$}&
  \setbox1\hbox{$R\times R$}%
  \mapsto\makebox[\wd1][c]{$f(v)$}
\end{align*}
```

and it is close to my intentions: I want the elements to be centered with respect to sets but the `\mapsto` has to be of the same length of `\to`.

What I don't like in this solution is that I must decide by myself which of the two is bigger (the set or the element) and I have to modify the code manually; e.g.:

```
\begin{align*}
  \setbox0\hbox{$(v_1,v_2)$}%
  f\colon\makebox[\wd0][c]{$R^2$}&
  \setbox1\hbox{$f((v_1,v_2))$}%
  \to\makebox[\wd1][c]{$R^2$}\\
  (v_1,v_2)&\mapsto f((v_1,v_2))%
\end{align*}
```