# Creating triangle commutative diagram with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, texlive, tikz-cd

I've just started using TikZ and need to create a simple triangle commutative diagram like this one. 
[image]

The closest I've been able to get is this. [image]

How do I get the *h* arrow to go from A2 to A3? Everything I've tried just causes errors.

Here's my current code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
A \arrow{r}{i}  \arrow{rd}{g} 
  & A3 \arrow{d}{h} \\
    & A2
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw commutative diagrams?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115783/how-to-draw-commutative-diagrams)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Why are you closing all the questions about tikz-cd? Even if they already have answers?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I thought that they are very similar to each other. Some answers are even alike. But you are right, I should probably review my own close votes again ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Update

A better syntax has evolved with time, which has several advantages due to improvements in Ti*k*Z and is now recommended.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 & A \arrow[dr,"g"] \\
B \arrow[ur,"f"] \arrow[rr,"h"] && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
 & A \arrow[dr,"g"] \\
B \arrow[ur,"f"] \arrow[rr,"h"] && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
 & A \arrow[dr,"g"] \\
B \arrow[ur,"f"] \arrow[rr,"h"] && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

#### Original answer

The basic idea for triangular diagrams is to consider more columns, in this case three; you may want to play with `column sep` or `row sep` in order to get better distances, as shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 & A \arrow{dr}{g} \\
B \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
 & A \arrow{dr}{g} \\
B \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
 & A \arrow{dr}{g} \\
B \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to try this with QTikZ, you need a suitable template; create the text file `tikz-cd-template.pgs` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
<>
\end{document}
```

Choose the template and then paste the part of the above code which is between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the input window for QTikZ. Here's a picture of the result.

If you have an old version of `tikz-cd` (which might be the case on Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux boxes) it may be necessary to start the diagram with `{}`:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
{} & A \arrow{dr}{g} \\
B \arrow{ur}{f} \arrow{rr}{h} && C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, your code doesn't work on my system (TeXLive running on Ubuntu 14.04 and using QTikZ for graphics editing and preview). Here's the error I'm getting:
`Missing character: There is no A in font nullfont!


[LaTeX] Line 2: Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
[LaTeX] Line 2: See the pgfbasematrix package documentation for explanation. ...                                                                                                
l.-5   &A \arrow{dr}{g} \\
                          
[LaTeX] Line 2:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF f`

Comment: @jaia Hmm, are you using that inside the argument to a command? What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of TeX Live. Not sure what you mean by "inside the argument to a command". (I'm mostly a LyX user and rarely deal with straight LaTeX.) I just pasted everything between the \begin{tikzcd} and \end{tikz} tags between those same tags in QTikZ.

Comment: Also, could you please point me to a good explanation of the column thing and how that works?

Comment: @jaia Sorry, but I know nothing of QTikZ and LyX. While I might try the former, I'm surely not going to test the latter.

Comment: LyX has nothing to do with this. I was just explaining my lack of familiarity with technical LaTeX stuff.

Comment: Just tried it out in TeX Studio and that doesn't work either, so it's not a QTikZ problem.The first error is `Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode & A \arrow{dr}{g} \\`.

Comment: @jaia I don't know what to say; *what* latest version of TeX Live are you running? If you're on Ubuntu, it's not the latest version, I'm afraid. Anyway, try with `{}` before the first `&`

Comment: That works, thanks! BTW, it's TeXLive version 2013.20140215-1.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it is easier for a newcomer to start by reading your update and if he is interested in the history, he will read it afterwards. Seen like that, it seems better to me that your update appears first and not last on your answer.

Comment: @AndréC You're right.