# Typesetting math diagrams

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[image: FIT]

I'm trying to learn how to produce math diagrams like this in Latex. I haven't had any luck finding stuff online because I don't really know what to search for. Any help?

Comment: It's very easy to do that with `tikz-cd` package, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191462/101651, for example.

Comment: I suggest that you read [J.S Milne's web page](http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html) about this subject.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Another solution is the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`.