# How to type this diagram in Latex

Tags: diagrams

I am a new latex user and I have no idea how to draw this diagram in latex. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I can draw the diagram in each line but I have no idea to draw the downward "=" and the down arrow

Comment: `\rotatebox{-90}{$\rightarrow$}` + some adjustment, for instance. Otherwise with `tikz-cd` or `psmatrix` (from `pst-node`).

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783/15036

Comment: The post @Thruston mentioned, should help you. There also good examples at texample.net: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram-tikz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution with tikz-cd as been suggested in the comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
y  \ar{r}{(E)} & v(y) \ar{r}{(T)} & T_{s}(v(y)) \ar{r} & \min\limits_{s \in S} T_{s}(v(y))\\
y^{*} \ar[equal]{d} \ar{r}{(E)} & v(y) \ar{r}{(T)} & T_{s}(v(y^{*})) \ar{d} \\
(y_{s})_{s \in S} \ar{r} {y^{*}_{s} > 0}& y^{*}_{s} \ar[equal]{r} & \min\limits_{s \in S}T_{s}(v(y^{*})) &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I can not get the equal "=", it turns out "---". I use beamer.

Comment: Please ask an independent question regarding the problem you're facing plus the code that generates the problem.