# How can I write a long equation in two lines and name it?

Tags: equations, tags

```
\begin{eqnarray} 
\tag{A8}  
 2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h \nonumber \\
&+& 89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f=0
\end{eqnarray}
```

But I am not getting the required equation with name A8.  If anyone can figure it out you're most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eqnarray`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\;2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h\nonumber\\
+&\;89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f\tag{A8}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My recommended version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h\\
+89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f\tag{A8}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @vijaybhatt Do you have any questions?

Comment: yes i want to know how can i make two sided arrow line like this:-                                 C1 <-------------- > C2   . I am using dash here but i need line with two sided arrow. If you can figure it out.

Comment: @vijaybhatt That is a new question, you should ask it, but make sure you read this question first: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783/156344. I am asking about questions related to this one and my answer.

Comment: @user156344 Where you skipped equal sign?