# How to create diagrams in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to make these two diagrams separately. I tried inserting these two images but they don't look like nice. How can I create them by my own.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with `tikz-cd` and `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[r] & \prescript{}{R}{A} \arrow[r, "\theta"] \arrow[d, "\phi", swap] & \prescript{}{R}{B}\arrow[dl, "\Psi"] \\%
 & \prescript{}{R}{X}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I forgot to write that I need the subscript to be on the right not on the left. That is, I need to wrtie `A_R`, `B_R`, and `X_R`. Another thing, how can I create the first diagram in my question with the row of `\psi` deleted.

Comment: Just delete `\arrow[dl, "\Psi"]` from your script.

Answer (score 3):

This approach using `tikz` will produce the same diagram with more open code: it is easier to comment out, delete or edit the individual lines.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.0cm,
    block/.style={ minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em}
    ]   
    % upper figure nodes  
    \node[block]               (Zeup){0};
    \node[right=of Zeup, block](ARup){$A_R$};
    \node[right=of ARup, block](BRup){$B_R$};
    \node[below=of ARup, block](XRup){$X_R$};
    \node[right=of BRup, block](exup){exact}; 
    
    % lower figure nodes
    \node[below=of XRup, block](ARlo){$A_R$};
    \node[left= of ARlo, block](Zelo){0};
    \node[right=of ARlo, block](BRlo){$B_R$};
    \node[below=of ARlo, block](XRlo){$X_R$};
    \node[right=of BRlo, block](exlo){exact}; 
    
    % upper  arrows
    \draw[->] (Zeup) -- (ARup);
    \draw[->] (ARup) -- node[pos=0.5,above]{$\theta$}(BRup);
    \draw[->] (ARup) -- node[pos=0.5,left]{$\phi$} (XRup);
    
    % lower arrows
    \draw[->] (Zelo) -- (ARlo);
    \draw[->] (ARlo) -- node[pos=0.5,above]{$\theta$}(BRlo);
    \draw[->] (ARlo) -- node[pos=0.5,left]{$\phi$} (XRlo);
    \draw[->] (BRlo) -- node[pos=0.5,below,sloped]{$\Psi$} (XRlo);   
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```