# How to write a xymatrix-like LaTeX environment?

Tags: xymatrix

I like to draw commutative diagrams using the `xymatrix` command. What I do not like is the fact that `xymatrix` is a command and not an environment. The structure of the `xymatrix` minilanguage is similar to some LaTeX environments that provide alignment of math formulas (`array`,`align` etc.), and it feels just weird to use a command in the `xymatrix` case.

I would like to define an environment that behaves exactly like the `xymatrix` command, but I do not know enough TeX to do that, so my naive attempts fail.

Could you write such an environment, or point me towards solution of my problem?

Comment: I've posted an answer using `\xymatrix`, but perhaps take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115783/how-to-draw-commutative-diagrams as `tikz-cd` is likely the best plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `b` argument type in `\NewDocumentEnviornment` to grab all of the content then pass to `\xymatrix`. For example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xyenv}{ob}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\xymatrix{#2}}{\xymatrix@#1{#2}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
U \ar@/_/[ddr]_y \ar@/^/[drr]^x
\ar@{.>}[dr]|-{(x,y)} \\
& X \times_Z Y \ar[d]^q \ar[r]_p
& X \ar[d]_f \\
& Y \ar[r]^g & Z }

\begin{xyenv}
  U \ar@/_/[ddr]_y \ar@/^/[drr]^x
  \ar@{.>}[dr]|-{(x,y)} \\
  & X \times_Z Y \ar[d]^q \ar[r]_p
  & X \ar[d]_f \\
  & Y \ar[r]^g & Z
\end{xyenv}

\xymatrix@C+1em{
U \ar@/_/[ddr]_y \ar@/^/[drr]^x
\ar@{.>}[dr]|-{(x,y)} \\
& X \times_Z Y \ar[d]^q \ar[r]_p
& X \ar[d]_f \\
& Y \ar[r]^g & Z }

\begin{xyenv}[C+1em]
  U \ar@/_/[ddr]_y \ar@/^/[drr]^x
  \ar@{.>}[dr]|-{(x,y)} \\
  & X \times_Z Y \ar[d]^q \ar[r]_p
  & X \ar[d]_f \\
  & Y \ar[r]^g & Z
\end{xyenv}

\end{document}
```

(In a real use, I might be minded to save `\xymatrix` with some internal name then create an environment called `xymatrix` here: for a demo, that looked a bit more risky.)

[image]

Comment: `\xymatrix` accepts some material before the `{` in order to set row and column spaces. Probably an argument list `O{}b` and doing `\xymatrix#1{#2}` would be better. And, of course, the option `cmtip` *must* be passed to `xy` or the arrows would be ugly as hell.

Comment: I'll adjust: oddly this is not something I'm familiar with!

Comment: It was a bit more complicated than I thought initially. I added an example of usage and the pictures.